# Программа вылетает после завершения импортированной функции

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

C++ DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "psapi.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct PROCINF {
    DWORD dwPID;
    LPWSTR lpMainModName;
} *LPPROCINF;


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetProcessInfo(LPPROCINF lppi)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, lppi->dwPID);

    if (hProcess == NULL) return;

    MessageBox(NULL, L"GET MAIN MOD NAME", NULL, NULL);

    //
    // Get process main module name.
    //

    lppi->lpMainModName = (LPWSTR)malloc(MAX_PATH * sizeof(wchar_t));
    GetModuleFileNameEx((HMODULE)hProcess, NULL, lppi->lpMainModName, MAX_PATH * sizeof(wchar_t));

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct PROCINF {
        public uint dwPID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpMainModName;
    }

    [DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void GetProcessInfo(ref PROCINF info);

    // ...

        PROCINF pinfo = new PROCINF();
        pinfo.dwPID = 3604;

        GetProcessInfo(ref pinfo);

        MessageBox.Show("PID: " + pinfo.dwPID + Environment.NewLine +
                "Main module: " + pinfo.lpMainModName);
```

После завершения `GetProcessInfo` сразу вылетает программа, причём без ошибок. В чём проблема понять не могу, т.к. вроде как импортирую правильно (если убрать `GetModuleFileNameEx` и `malloc`, заменив заполнение значения пустой строкой, всё будет работать хорошо).

Comment: Если dll ваша, я бы посоветовал писать её на C++/CLI и предоставлять сразу managed-интерфейс.

Comment: Malloc судя по всему является проблемой, маллокнутые значения нельзя передавать через границу DLL (т. к. никто не знает, как их вернуть назад).

Comment: И что предлагаете на замену?

Comment: Если хотите, напишу в качестве ответа, решение на C++/CLI.

Comment: Чтобы выяснить причину вылетания, попробуйте установить флажок Break on Exceptions (Shift-Alt-E в студии), причем как С++ Exceptions, так и CLR Exceptions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/ и запустите программу в режиме отладки (F5).

Comment: @VladD Конечно я не против)

Comment: @Sergey Slepov Это не помогло. Я выбрал все CLR и все C++ исключения. Программа вылетает в этом месте без исключения.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov Так же хотел бы спросить у вас, вот это поможет обрабатывать все исключения при помощи try catch блока или как? А если типо не установить, то просто будет программа вылетать с исключением, которое не обрабатывается даже try catch блоком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение с библиотекой на C++/CLI.

1. Добавьте в проект библиотеку на C++/CLI. В Visual Studio 2017 это называется «CLR class library».
2. Положите в этой библиотеке в заголовочном файле следующие определения:

   ```
   #pragma once

   #include "windows.h"
   #include "psapi.h"

   using namespace System;

   namespace InteropLibrary
   {
       public ref class ProcInf
       {
       public:
           UInt16 ProcessId;
           String^ MainModuleName;
       };

       public ref class ProcessHelper abstract sealed // аналог статического класса
       {
       public:
           static Boolean GetProcessInfo(ProcInf^ lppi)
           {
               HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(
                       PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                       FALSE,
                       lppi->ProcessId);

               if (hProcess == NULL) return false;

               wchar_t moduleName[MAX_PATH + 1];
               // размер в символах, поэтому не удваиваем его
               auto nameSize = GetModuleFileNameEx(
                       (HMODULE)hProcess, NULL, moduleName, MAX_PATH);
               if (nameSize > 0)
                   lppi->MainModuleName = gcnew String(moduleName, 0, nameSize);

               CloseHandle(hProcess);
               return nameSize > 0;
           }
       };
   }
   ```

   О том, как создавать сигнатуры методов для C++/CLI, можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx).
3. В C#-части выберите таргет с конкретной битностью (x86 или x64). Подключите часть на C++/CLI как project reference.
4. В C#-коде вызывайте:

   ```
   InteropLibrary.ProcInf pi = new InteropLibrary.ProcInf() { ProcessId = 1234 };
   if (InteropLibrary.ProcessHelper.GetProcessInfo(pi))
   {
       ...
   ```

Вот вроде бы и всё.

---

Не забудьте: если в вашем проекте есть неуправляемый код, вы привносите в него undefined behaviour и все остальные «прелести» нативного доступа к памяти. Поэтому будьте предельно осторожны с нативными функциями. (Например, вы неправильно подсчитали размер буфера, нативное программирование таких ошибок не прощает.)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65543/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----).